# Explicit isomorphism of tensor product of fields $L \otimes_K L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of fields with Galois group $G$. There is a well-known isomorphism of $K$-algebras
$$L \otimes_K L \to \prod_{\sigma \in G} L$$ given on pure tensors by $a \otimes b \mapsto (a\sigma(b))_\sigma$. This can be found for example in Bourbaki's Algebra V.10.4.

I am struggling to find an explicit description of the inverse isomorphism. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Here's my two cents. The map itself is given on pure tensors so finding a nice description of the inverse is hard unless you make some choices. I'd suggest fixing a basis of $L/K$ which then give a basis of $\prod_{\sigma\in G}L$, and then define the inverse map on those basis elements.

Comment: If you allow yourself to use the normal basis theorem, this becomes really easy.